# Coldfusion & Amazon S3 - Setting the Content Type?

Tags: coldfusion, amazon-s3

I've used Amazon S3 for content for a while now, but I've just run across an instance where I need to set the content type for uploaded images (need to do this at the point of upload).  I've tried a few things, but can't seem to nail the correct syntax for StoreSetMetaData.

This is how I'm doing it right now...

```
<cfset meta = [{content_type="Image"}]>

<cfset StoreSetMetadata("s3://mybucket/#bgfull#", "#meta#")>
```

The rest of the code isnt necessary, so I've just pasted in the relevant 2 lines.

Using this syntax, I get the following error;

"500 You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members."

Pointers much appreciated! I haven't been able to track down a single syntax example for this.

Comment: if meta is accessed as a structure, shouldn't it just be a structure instead of an array with a structure on first index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the online documentation of [StoreSetMetadata](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSd160b5fdf5100e8f-4439fdac128193edfd6-7efc.html) the second argument is of type struct, and not of type array.

Try

```
<cfset meta = {content_type="Image"}>

<cfset StoreSetMetadata("s3://mybucket/#bgfull#", meta)>
```

Comment: Just to be picky, don't forget you don't need "# around that second argument: <cfset storeSetMetadata("..", meta)>